# Listar acompanhamentos de um itens de uma venda com mysql

Tags: mysql

Tabela 1 - venda
id_venda

Tabela 2 - item_pedido
id | id_venda | id_pastel

Tabela 3 - item_acompanhamento
id | id_item_pedido | id_acompanhamento

Exemplo: Realizo uma venda com dois itens e seus acompanhamentos:

**Um pastel:**
carne(item_pedido)
**Acompanhamentos(item_acompanhamento)**
cebola e salsa.

**Um pastel:**
frango(item_pedido)
**Acompanhamento:**
catupiry(item_acompanhamento).

Separadamente eu até consigo trazer:

```
SELECT venda.id_venda, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(item_pedido.id_pastel) AS id_pastel 
FROM venda 
JOIN item_pedido ON item_pedido.id_venda = venda.id_venda GROUP BY item_pedido.id_venda
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
SELECT item_pedido.id_venda, item_pedido.id_pastel,
GROUP_CONCAT(item_acompanhamento.id_acompanhamento) AS id_acompanhamento 
FROM item_pedido 
JOIN item_acompanhamento ON item_pedido.id = item_acompanhamento.id_item_pedido 
GROUP BY item_pedido.id
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém gostaria de trazer apenas uma venda com os dois itens com seus respectivos acompanhamentos.

Comment: _gostaria de trazer apenas uma venda com os dois itens com seus respectivos acompanhamentos_ e não é exatamente isso que esse resultado de consulta esta mostrando?

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza o `distinct` no `SELECT` que fazes. Penso que ele apresenta o conjunto ou o último registo inserido com o id_venda.

```
SELECT DISTINCT item_pedido.id_venda, item_pedido.id_pastel,
GROUP_CONCAT(item_acompanhamento.id_acompanhamento) AS id_acompanhamento 
FROM item_pedido 
JOIN item_acompanhamento ON item_pedido.id = item_acompanhamento.id_item_pedido 
GROUP BY item_pedido.id
```

Caso não resulte, a ideia é criar uma tabela auxiliar que junte as vendas comuns.

Comment: Agradeço a resposta mas com o DISTINCT não funcionou. Não entendi a segunda opção sobre criar uma tabela auxiliar para juntar as vendas comuns.

Comment: Estive a pensar melhor na solução e só não entendo o porquê de juntar a venda... queres uma linha a dizer 11,95 - 2,5,6 ? assim não consegues distinguir as vendas...

Comment: Queria algo do tipo 11,2 e 95,5,6, onde 11 é a venda e 2 é o acompanhamento.

Comment: Se funcionar, era concatenar a venda e o acompanhamento com uma vírgula no meio... Views, se calhar ajudavam, digo eu... Se estiveres a mostrar em PHP consegues fazer tranquilamente.

Comment: Conseguir resolver do jeito que está ai mesmo. Como a primeira query retorna os dois id's, pequei os mesmos e com outro select obtive o resultado que queria. Agradeço sua ajuda.